# iOS - How to download files in order using List All

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to Firebase, and was trying to download all images from a folder, while trying to keep them in order inside an URL array.

I used the function `listAll` to get an array of references with all the images, and then loop through them, downloading the URL and inserting them in the `itemImagesURL` array. When we have looped through all the images, the array is returned using a `completionHandler`.

The main problem of doing this is that the array is filled by the images in the wrong order, because each item doesn´t take the same to download the url (and append it to the array).

Is there a way to do download the URL of each item, keeping the original order of the `result.items` reference array?

My code is as follows:

```
 func getItemImages(completionHandler: @escaping ([URL?]) -> Void) {

    var itemImagesURL: [URL] = []

    // We retrieve all images using listAll
    downloadRef.listAll(completion: { result, error in

        if let error = error {
            print("Error listing item images: ", error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        itemImagesURL.reserveCapacity(result.items.count)

        // We download every image's url
        for index in 0 ..< result.items.count {

             result.items[index].downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    //Handle any errors
                    print("Error downloading item image: ", error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                } else {
                    // Get download URL
                    itemImagesURL.insert(url!, at: index)

                    // All the urls of the item's images are retrieved -> we escape
                    if itemImagesURL.count == result.items.count {
                        print("Item's Images download finished.")
                        completionHandler(itemImagesURL)
                    }

                }
            })
        }

    })  // list all
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of appending to the array, you could simply use the index of the current item that you're iterating.  You'll have to pre-allocate an array of the correct size first.

Comment: I did it already, and keep getting them in the wrong order. (I preallocated it using:                `itemImagesURL.reserveCapacity(result.items.count)` , and inserted it using                         `itemImagesURL.insert(url!, at: index)`, changing the loop to `for index in 0 ..< result.items.count `. This probably happens because when it gets to the completion Block of `downloadURL`, the index has changed.

Comment: Maybe you would like to edit the question to show the updated code that uses an index?

Comment: Sure. I am on it.

Comment: Done. I still don't understand why the index changes when it's in the completionBlock of downloadURL... maybe it has already looped to the next iteration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a thought. I generally find I want to store with other stuff with my image, like an image name, the image itself, the date posted, etc so I like to have a class to hold those items.

```
class ImageInfoClass {
    var name = ""
    var url = "some url"
    var index: Int!
    var image: Image()
}
```

Then an array to store them in - could be used as a dataSource for a tableView for example.

```
var myImageArray = [ImageInfoClass]()
```

Then read them in from storage... Once the last one has been read in, sort by index and you're set.

```
func loadImagesAndSort() {
    for (index, imageUrl) in result.items.enumerated() {
        //perform download
        // for each image that's downloaded, create a ImageInfoClass object
        //   and populate with the image, the index and a image name for example
        let imageInfo = ImageInfoClass()
        imageInfo.name = name
        imageInfo.index = index
        imageInfo.image = //the image
        self.myImageArray.append(imageInfo)

        if index == lastImageIndex {
           self.myImageArray.sort(by: { $0.index < $1.index})
           //print to show they are sorted
           self.myImageArray.forEach { print($0.index, $0.name)}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I just solved it using a Dictionary pair of Index and URL, and sorting it afterwards, which is really close to what you pointed!

Comment: @Brolivar Absolutely! You could also leverage Tuple or a host of other options. If you just need the image url, then an array of dictionary {index, imageUrl} is super clean.